# Looking for key-repeat data in WM_INPUT message

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, raw-input

I just started using Raw Input for my app. 
Getting straight to the question, in the legacy `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, the `lParam` could be checked to obtain extra information about the key press. Like these-

```
 Bits   Meaning
    0-15    The repeat count for the current message. 
            The value is the number of times the keystroke is autorepeated as a         
            result of the user holding down the key. If the keystroke is 
            held long enough, multiple messages are sent. However, the repeat 
            count is not cumulative.
   16-23    The scan code. The value depends on the OEM.
   24       Indicates whether the key is an extended key, such as the right-hand
            ALT and CTRL keys that appear on an enhanced 101- or 102-key 
            keyboard. The value is 1 if it is an extended key; otherwise, it is
            0.
   25-28    Reserved; do not use.
   29       The context code. The value is always 0 for a WM_KEYDOWN message.
   30       The previous key state. The value is 1 if the key is down before the
            message is sent, or it is zero if the key is up.
   31       The transition state. The value is always 0 for a WM_KEYDOWN
            message.
```

I want to know if a `WM_INPUT` message is for a repeated key, so that I can ignore that message.(turn off keyrepeat.)

The trouble I am having is that this information can't be found for the `WM_INPUT` message. the `lParam` of the `WM_INPUT` message contains the handle to a `RAWINPUT` structure. On doing some research, I found that inside `RAWINPUT::header` contains a member called wparam in it and MSDN describes it as

> `wParam`
>         Type: `WPARAM`
>         The value passed in the `wParam` parameter of the `WM_INPUT` message.

Will I find the required information in here or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Try logging the `WM_INPUT` messages to the console/debug window.  IIRC the system sends you a `WM_INPUT` for each of the repeats.

Comment: @theB yes, that i am aware of. I want to know if a message is a repeated one so that i can ignore it. I'll update the question with this info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RAW Input API does not provide repeat counts.  It is *raw* data coming from the keyboard directly. The repeat count is calculated at a higher level when the `WM_KEY...` messages are generated.  Using `WM_INPUT`, you will have to manually keep track of the down/up states of each key to determine their repeat counts yourself.  When a key goes down, start counting each `WM_INPUT` message for that key.  When the key goes up, stop counting it.

Comment: yes, that does answer my question, but i am still curios about what that `RAWINPUT::header::wParam` contains...

Comment: It contains exactly what the [`RAWINPUTHEADER` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645571.aspx) says it contains: "*The value passed in the wParam parameter of the WM_INPUT message*". And if you read the [`WM_INPUT` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx), it says the `wParam` parameter is "***The input code. This parameter can be one of the following values: RIM_INPUT (0) RIM_INPUTSINK(1)**.*" So there you go, the `header.wParam` value specifies whether the app was in the foreground or not during the input.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same information you are looking for, and I found a reasonable work-around.  I didn't care about the key repeat count, I just wanted to know if a `WM_INPUT` message represents an auto-repeat ***even if the initial key press occurred while my application was not in focus and the key continued to be held when focus switched to my application.***

Throwing out all but the first `WM_INPUT` message is not sufficient to discern this, as keys held prior to gaining focus will look like new key events after gaining focus.  You need the information in `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_SYSKEYDOWN` lparam bit 30, and it's apparently not available from `WM_INPUT`.

We work around this by requesting to continue receiving legacy input messages when registering for raw input by omitting the `RIDEV_NOLEGACY` flag.  We get both raw and legacy messages, which arrive interleaved.  For any relevant `WM_INPUT` message containing key information, it will be followed by legacy messages relating to that key before any additional `WM_INPUT` messages arrive.  Our Windows input library gathers key info from both raw & legacy messages before evaluating the key event and it works very well for us.